# merge multiple files in several subdirectories into 1 file for each subdirectory and delete original files

Tags: shell-script, files, directory-structure

I have a **directory structure**

```
DIR
        SUBDIR1
                    11-01-11.txt
                    13-05-23.txt

        SUBDIR2
                    12-05-56.txt
                    13-04-02.txt
                    15-04-06.txt
```

I would like to write a bash script that leads to this **Desired output**

```
DIR
        SUBDIR1
                    sub_dir1_merged.txt

        SUBDIR2
                    sub_dir2_merged.txt
```

I would like to maintain the original directory structure, merge files into a single sub_dirname_merged.txt file for each and delete all original files.

I tried the following **code**

```
for f in */
do
cat $f/*.txt > "$f"/$f_merged.txt
rm $f/*.txt 
done
```

this does not work fully.

Comment: Your redirection `>` doesn't *append* the content, it *rewrites* the file every loop. You have to use `>>`.

Comment: okay, i can try out the append >>  but how to delete the original files while keeping the new.txt file?

Comment: The problem is you are looping over the do directories, no the txt files.

Comment: can you suggest a different approach with commands? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script:

```
for f in */*.txt; do 
  cat "$f" >> "$(dirname "$f")/$(dirname "$f")_merged.txt" 
  rm "$f"
done
```

---

Loop the txt files across the subdirectories:

```
for f in */*.txt; do
```

---

```
$(dirname "$f")
```

returns the name of the folder in which the txt resides wich is used both to name the file and the path to save the file.

---

```
rm "$f"
```

removes the file. When you are going to use `rm` command be sure the result of the script is what you expected before executing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` in combination with `-execdir` flag. It gets as simple as the  following:

```
find DIR/ -type f -execdir bash -c 'cat -- $1 >> "${PWD##*/}_merged.txt"' _ {} \;
```

I slightly modified the above one-liner so the original files are removed.

```
find DIR/ -type f -execdir bash -c 'for f; do cat -- $f >> "${PWD##*/}_merged.txt"; done;  [[ $f != *${PWD##*/}* ]] && rm -v "$f"' _ {} \;
```